# itext PDF - Locking pdf after specified time

Tags: security, pdf, passwords, itext

I am creating a "Password Protected" pdf using iText pdf library. 
What I want is to "corrupt or say expire the password" after 24 hours, irrespective of the person being online or offline.

More details :- A user downloads a password protected pdf from my website and I want to make this pdf available only for 24 hours, after that the password should expire or pdf should be corrupted , overall it should be of not open after 24 hours. This should work even if the user is offline.

Please avoid suggesting javascript in pdf, that works, but for any technical person, its a piece of cake to change the system time before and after download or may be disable script.

I need a concrete solution which works on any system.

@bruno-Lowagie, your help will be highly appreciated sir.

- Sumit

Comment: You're looking for a DRM system and there are no open source DRM systems available. Your requirement that the system also works offline is also impossible. Elementary logic should be sufficient to understand that what you require is impossible in general: it would be sufficient to print the document to another upon receiving it to work around your limitation (even if printing isn't allowed, there are ways to work around this unless you buy a DRM solution).

Comment: In addition to @BrunoLowagie's explanation: If you look into password protection as specified in the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), you'll see that there is no mention of expiring the password. Thus, even if you find some solution, it won't be a *solution which works on any system*; maybe it requires JavaScript (not all PDF viewers support JavaScript), maybe it requires an Adobe Reader plugin (pretty Adobe-centric), maybe it even requires a custom PDF viewer...